# Next.js NODE_OPTIONS is not compatible with yarn v2

Tags: node.js, next.js, yarnpkg, yarn-v2, yarnpkg-v2

Important info:

- yarn 2 (berry)
- Next.js

I have a following script to run Next.js app (either next dev or next start), and to initialise Datadog APM tracing:
`"dev": "NODE_OPTIONS='-r ./utils/tracer.js' next dev"`

Since I need to use a dependency in `tracer.js`, I'm also using `.pnp.cjs` initialisation so node is able to understand `.yarn` folder:

```
require('../.pnp.cjs').setup();

const tracer = require('dd-trace')

...
```

the command seems to execute successfully, but as soon as I actually enter the web app, I get this:

[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJTIl.png)

there seems to be a problem with resolving imports, it already narrows down to `@tanstack-react-query-virtual-e64c51...`

Help greatly appreciated, I didn't think integrating with yarn 2 would be such a pain long-term

What works is when I use nodeLinker: node-modules, but I want to stay with .yarn linking since it's the default, main mode right now.